# vscode и таб при переносе тега

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, настройки

Помогите, уже триллион нервных клеток убил. В vscode когда пишешь html тег и нажимаешь enter оно просто делает перенос строки и получается как то вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя раньше такой дичи небыло, если нажимал enter (находясь между открывающим и закрывающим тегом) то vscode сразу делал дополнительный перенос и по середине сразу добавлял таб, выглядило вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это невероятно бесит когда приходится писать разметку, а как это загуглить ума не приложу, самое близкое что находил это у чувака такой перенос был но в scss, по его решению на решение своей проблемы так и не вышел. А причину почему эта настройка сбилась тоже не знаю. Прошу, спасите мои оставшиеся нервы

Вот еще скрин setting.json, не сильно шарю но покомментировал параметры относящиеся к html.format, ничего не произошло, даже полностью удалил все настройки, тоже безтолку. Вывод: здесь чегото наоборот не хватает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может посмотреть в файле "settings.json", вдруг там что-то поменялось в разделе `"html...."`. По дефолту все нормально работает.

Comment: С тем же самым сейчас столкнулся. Шляпа какая-то...

Comment: EditorConfig присутствует в проекте?

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой. **Для меня вот что сработало:**

Внизу-справа VSCode подписывает формат файла. У меня он был определён как ***PHP*** (У вас может какой-нибудь другой стоять).
Я нажал на него и в списке выбрал ***HTML***, после этого переносы тегов при начали работать так как и должны были :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

А я эту проблему решила так:

в параметрах в поиске вводим `Editor: Auto Indent` - делаем активную вкладку
`Пользователь` и выбираем `full`.